# Principal Component Analysis vs Linear Discriminant Analysis and Leave-one-out Cross Validation

Tags: pca, cross-validation, discriminant-analysis

I have 2 samples: disease (n=21) vs no disease (n=13). I am using  histogram features (percentiles) of 8 different type of diagnostic tests. Individual "histograms" are built using hundreds of pixel values over one anatomical location. "Tests" are different imaging modalities.

I want to know which test out of the 8 considered and which histogram feature (e.g. *x* percentile) of the corresponding test performs best in correctly classifying patients into disease vs no disease groups. In addition I'd also like to know if makes sense to run a leave-one-out cross validation.

I would really appreciate any input on what statistical method fits best for this scope. You can tell I have little to none background on the matter. I apologize if all this sounds basically like a nonsense, although I've been reading a lot of papers in my field (diagnostic imaging) using these methods.